# Python: How to stop function execution from outside

Tags: python, function, exception, functional-programming, execution

I have the following problem:

i have a GUI with two Buttons: "Run" and "Stop".

When I press Button "Run", function **a** will be executed.

How can I stop the execution by pressing Button "Stop", *without* any *if statements*? In function **a**, there are a ton of mathematical calculations so if I would just border the code inside the function **a** with a loop and check once per loop-pass if the Button "Stop" was pressed, it would take too much time.

I want to stop the execution of the function **a** right now, not when the whole calculations are finished. So for example to border the code inside the function with try/catch but raising the exception outside of the function, then I could stop the execution of the function everytime I want, not until the if-statement would be reached. I allready tried to solve the Problem with a thread but it doesn't work because I don't know, how to start a thread with commit some parameters to the Custom thread-class.

Here a small Pythoncode that should show what I mean:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        #Initialization of Button "Run",connect Button "Run" to function a
        #Initialization of Button "Stop",connect Button "Stop" to function b

    def a(self):
        """calculation of a ton of mathematical stuff, can take MORE THAN 
           FIVE MINUTES to be finished, could be grouped in
           individual functions to border the function-calls with try/catch,
           but would be inefficient and inelegant"""
        pass

    def b(self):
        """Should stop the execution of function a immediately """
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how your code is structured. It's difficult to answer your question without it. What GUI framework are you using? How do user events trigger function calls? As to your thread comment, I suggest you read about them some more and try experimenting with them (and multiprocessing) to figure it out. If you want your GUI to remain responsive during background operations, you will likely need multiple threads of execution or processes.

Comment: You need to have a look at Davis Beazley's very long talk on generators called Generators: the Final Frontier. Utilizing the `yield from` statement you can craft a function that can be stopped at any point you specify.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I added some code, the GUI is coded with PyQt5, the buttons are connected to the functions with the "signal and slot" - technology